# Relatório no iReport com JAVA

Tags: java

Estou com uma grande dúvida na manutenção de um relatório em JAVA. Trabalho com um sistema de gestão de contratos e estou fazendo a melhoria de um relatório para que os mesmos mostrem os empenhos entre as versões do contrato. De forma mais clara, atualmente o sistema só busca do contrato principal, mas o cliente quer que busque também dos versionamentos(renovações contratuais). O problema é que a pessoa que fez o relatório está criando uma lista com todos os empenhos e mesmo que eu mude o critério e apareça os empenhos dessa tal renovação, ainda sim gostaria que dentro do relatório ele dividisse os empenhos por contrato, mas não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer. Alguém tem alguma dica?

```
if(SimpleValidate.isNullOrBlank(numeroContrato)){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Número contrato Obrigatório");
        return;
    }
    try {
        ContratoCriteria criteria = new ContratoCriteria();
        criteria.setNumeroContratoDocumento(numeroContrato);
        List<RelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBean> relatorios = financeiroService.buscarRelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBeanPorNumContrato(criteria);

        if (SimpleValidate.isNotNullOrEmpty(relatorios)) {
            Long idOrgao = relatorios.get(0).getIdOrgao();
            exibirRelatorio(relatorios, idOrgao);
            init();
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(FacesUtil.getMessageByKey("contrato.relatorioFinanceiroSintetico.msg.nenhumRegistro"));
        }
    } catch (PlanoInternoInexistenteException e) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(FacesUtil.getMessageByKey("contrato.relatorioFinanceiroSintetico.msg.planoInternoNaoEncontrada"));
    } catch (UnidadeGestoraNaoEncontradaException e) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(FacesUtil.getMessageByKey("contrato.relatorioFinanceiroSintetico.msg.unidadeGestoraNaoEncontrada"));
    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(FacesUtil.getMessageByKey("contrato.relatorioFinanceiroSintetico.msg.nenhumRegistro"));
    }
```

basicamente nesse trecho ele faz a busca a partir de uma critéria que instancia ali mesmo passando o dado que ele recupera da tela(numeroContrato).

```
@Override
public List<RelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBean> buscarRelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBeanPorNumContrato(ContratoCriteria criteria) throws ApplicationException {

    List<ContratoView> listaContratos = contratoViewBO.findByCriteria(criteria, 0, 0, null);

    List<RelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBean> listaRelatorio = new ArrayList<RelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBean>();

    if (SimpleValidate.isNotNullOrEmpty(listaContratos)) {
        iniciarMapasDeDadosDoCompras();
        for (ContratoView contratoView : listaContratos) {
            listaRelatorio.addAll(carregarRelatorioEmpenhosEPagamentosContratoBean(contratoView));
        }
    }
    return listaRelatorio;
}
```

Aqui eu imaginei que nesse for ele fosse dividir o contrato em dois... Original e versionamento, mas isso não acontece.